# Simple Inheritance Gets Vtable Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

So I am trying to compile this simple code:

```
// In Test.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{

public:
    virtual string f (string&);
};

class B : public A{

public:
    B (string);
    string f (string&);
};

// In Test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;


B :: B (string row){
    cout << "HERE";
}

string B :: f (string& x){
    cout << "Test";
}
```

It seems simple enough but I keep getting a `Undefined reference to 'vtable for A'` error (compiler is MINGW with Eclipse IDE). When I take out the constructor implementation for B, the code compiles fine. What am I missing or is this a linker error?

Comment: Nope. The code I wrote is all that is there besides a main that has a simple `return 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either have to make `A::f(string&)` abstract by writing `= 0` at the end of the declaration, or actually provide an implementation of `A::f`

Since currently the virtual function `A::f` does not exist, the compiler cannot create a vtable for it (the virtual function table).

Comment: You win : ). Any reasons why the function has to be pure virtual rather than only virtual and why removing the constructor implementation lets it compile?

Comment: Only virtual (nonabstract) function expects a function implementation to create the vtable. vtable basically holds an address of all virtual functions. No idea why removing constructor allows for the compilation (it shouldn't). The problem would reappear on some other spot sooner or later...

Comment: @ShardulUpadhyay: You just *declared* a function and did not *define* it.You need to define a function for linker to link to its compiled definition.Pure virtual function maynot have a definition & hence making the function pure virtual will work or you need to define it.

Comment: Of course you would be able to provide a default implementation (`virtual string f (string&) {}`) in base-class as well and compiler would be happy. But if logically it doesn't make sense for base class version of `f()` to have impl, then it must be pure virtual as Cygnus mentioned.

Comment: @thekashyap: Given the code sample,it is difficult to say the need for the function to be pure virtual or not.For the record A function can be Pure virtual and yet have a definition and yes it helps in certain cases.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanations. Ended up going with an implementation for A::f rather than make it a pure virtual function.

Comment: @Als: Pure-virtual functions may very well have an implementation. They just don't need to.

Comment: @Als - "it is difficult to say..." => Yes, that's true. So? Prime reason for my comment was to say there are 2 options, pick the right one.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't see the point of disagreement between my comment and yours.

Comment: @Als: It's nothing deep, just because you said that pv functions *may not* have (= are not allowed to have) a definition... so I thought I'd clarify that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ah okay :) *Pedantism* getting the better of me :P Oh, Just noticed though my comment said pv can have definition not *may not*. Ahem..

Comment: @Als: Ah, apologies! I didn't see your second comment -- all's well then!